# AJAX contact form with user data

Tags: php, ajax, contacts

I have built a contact form that checks for errors and submits using AJAX. The problem is that I also want it to take the users data (email, first name, and last name) and store it in the database.

The contact form was working fine until I wanted to accomplish the second goal. The database is WordPress driven so it was a simple matter of wp_insert_user. Obviously the PHP file needed the header information to access the database so I added the_header() to the PHP file and the entire function now does not work. I have tested it through Firebug and it should be working but nothing happens; no validation and no email.

The contact form is here. I wondered if someone could figure out the problem

http://www.divethegap.com/update/contact

Any ideas?
EDIT --

After misunderstandings in the commentary I have removed the offending the_header() line from the PHP file. This will now disable the function that would have inserted the users data into the database but will show you how the form works and thus that this line is causing a problem. A problem I may point out that has not stopped any of my other ajax functions working.

http://www.divethegap.com/update/contact/

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dd' of undefined` - based off this line `var menu=new menu.dd("menu");`

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with it since all the other ajax functions are fully functional

Comment: which browser are you testing it on? form won't submit on chrome

Comment: THe form should not submit as it is AJAX

Comment: if a form is not submitted then no data can be injected into the Database.

Comment: Wrong. The form is submitted via AJAX. The AJAX utilises a PHP file that can be accessed at http://www.divethegap.com/update/contact?send That PHP file is executed and data is returned to the form via json. All this was working perfectly fine until the addition of the insert_user function was added requiring the header to be in the PHP file. I have a similar function executed from a from submitted via ajax that creates posts. It works fine and is almost exactly the same. Hence I do not understand why this one does not.

Comment: I've edited the question and also the page to show you how the function performs perfectly if I remove the_header() line. Now you can see how the form works but with that line removed it will never create the user

Comment: The goal of AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript And XML) is to send DATA and receive some. If you inspect your AJAX request, the data return is divethegap.com/update/contact?send HTML, not JSON. EDIT : and as I'm writing this, it worked, nevermind.

Comment: All fixed. It was being caused by an existing ajax function inside the core of the database that for various ludicrously complicated and highly irritating reasons was causing problems. All fixed now working with JS enabled and disabled. Thanks for help to all